How to take a screen shot using GIMP?
I'm trying to figure out how to use GIMP. But no matter what, I can't figure it out. Can you help me?

GIMP is not a screenshot program.  It's an image editor.  Use the system's installed screenshot taking application and then edit the screenshot in GIMP after.

Your question is ambiguous.  What are you trying to actually achieve? And what is your actual question?  For what purpose your trying to take screenshots?  Do you just want screenshots in Gimp, or in your whole computer?  You lead with asking how to take a screenshot, and then you ask a much broader questions.

@ThomasWard, gimp does have an inbuilt screenshot function.

You can use Gimp to take a screen shot, using File > Create > Screenshot:


Personally, I prefer other tools (I use KSnip), if only because annotating the image with Gimp is tedious (and a lot of my screenshots are the Gimp UI, and using Gimp to edit Gimp UI screenshot gets you lost very fast...).

I too use GIMP to take screenshots. Please also understand that GIMP is not a screenshot tool.  It is a sophisticated graphic editing tool. My technique is

Press the print screen key
Indicate I want to open the image with GIMP.  Some times I just say I was to copy the image to the clipboard, manually open GIMP then paste the image into GIMP.
In GIMP I usually crop the image using the the crop tool (found under tools, transformation tools).
Finally I either print the image directly from GIMP or, export it to an image format such as png or jpg.  The export is found under file.  Note also that you need to specify not just the name of the image you want but the file extension as well.  The file extension tells GIMP how to create the correct format for the export.

GIMP is great.  It will take several minutes to learn enough about it to make these simple screen images.  Beyond that, there is MUCH more to GIMP that you can learn as time permits in the future.

You’re not using gimp to take a screenshot - you’re using the inbuilt screenshot utility to do that and then using gimp to edit it.

Gimp does have inbuilt screenshot functionality.
